# Returning an Integer from RESTful web services method in java

Tags: java, web-services, rest

Am new to RESTful web services. I wrote a web service method and am currently returning an XML by using `@Produces(MediaType.TEXT_XML)`. But the requirement is that my web service method must return an Integer instead of XML. How can I achieve this? kindly help me with this. Below is the method I wrote.

```
@Path("{type}/{token}")
@GET
@Produces(MediaType.TEXT_XML)
public String setToken(@Context HttpServletRequest request, @Context HttpServletResponse response, @PathParam("type") String type, @PathParam("token") String token) throws ServletException, IOException {
    String value=token;
    if(request==null){
        System.out.println("Request null");
    }

    System.out.println("Token: " + value);
    System.out.println("AnumLotnum: " + type);

    if(request!=null){
        request.setAttribute("param", value);
        request.getRequestDispatcher("/dummy").include(request, response);
    }

    String id=request.getAttribute("ID").toString();
    return "<token>"+ "<value>"+id+"</value>" + "</token>";
}
```

Comment: you can return that integer value in XML tags in you response XML.. and parse that response XML at consuming side to get required integer value from XML

Answer (score 4):

Use     `@Produces(MediaType.TEXT_PLAIN)` instead of `@Produces(MediaType.TEXT_XML)`

It will be text as you are using RESTful Webservices which is a pure HTTP implementation(Hyper TEXT Transfer Protocol).

To get an integer you can either cast at Client side manually.

Actually you have two options you may either return **String** or **int**, both will do. By returning int, a smart Client like Jersey Http client will automatically cast the String to int for you.

Example

```
  @Path("{type}/{token}")
    @GET
    @Produces(MediaType.TEXT_PLAIN)
    public int setToken(@Context HttpServletRequest request, @Context HttpServletResponse response, @PathParam("type") String type, @PathParam("token") String token) throws ServletException, IOException {
return 1;     
}
```