# RESTFUL web service - media type=application/xml

Tags: java, rest, web-services

I'm currently writing a RESTFUL web service and trying to return integer to the web service.

I encounter 500 Internal Server Error from the browser and when I check the Tomcat Log, the above error occurred.

```
12-Nov-2018 09:47:12.547 SEVERE [http-nio-8080-exec-52] org.glassfish.jersey.message.internal.WriterInterceptorExecutor$TerminalWriterInterceptor.aroundWriteTo MessageBodyWriter not found for media type=application/xml, type=class java.lang.Integer, genericType=int.
```

My code :

```
@POST
    @Path("/post")

    @Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_XML)
    public static int adaptiveAuth(){ 
        int message=1;
        return message; 
    }
```

If I replace the function with String, it wont give any error.

```
@POST
    @Path("/post")

    @Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_XML)
    public static String adaptiveAuth(){ 
        String message="POST STRING";
        return message; 
    }
```

Result : POST STRING

Is there any limitation on RESTFUL regarding MediaType.APPLICATION_XML ?

Thank you

Comment: Scalar values can't be represented as valid XML documents, with the exception of a String, which doesn't go through any type of validation. It is just sent out as it, putting the responsibility on the developer to return a valid XML string. Unless you want to construct the XML string yourself, generally with XML, we use POJOs to map the XML elements and attributes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hello try to use Response object from jax-rs specification

https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/ws/rs/core/Response.html

It’s better to return response object which gives you flexibility to define status , body etc.

Also you can see existing answer on this topic:

[Returning an Integer from RESTful web services method in java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32835793/returning-an-integer-from-restful-web-services-method-in-java)