# 415-UnSupported Media Type

Tags: rest, web-services, postman

While performing testing RESTFUL Web Service using POSTMAN, I encountered the below error :

> 415 UnSupported Media Type

Currently in my code, I'm using MediaType.TEXT_PLAIN. This is due to one of the answer from page [enter link description here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32835793/returning-an-integer-from-restful-web-services-method-in-java) telling that if you need to return integer, you need to use TEXT_PLAIN.

May I know is the data that I provide in the web service is compatible with TEXT_PLAIN or not.

```
@POST
@Path("/post")
@Produces(MediaType.TEXT_PLAIN)

public int adaptiveAuth( @FormDataParam("uuid") String uuID, 
        @FormDataParam("browserinfo") String browserInfo, 
        @FormDataParam("ipint") long ipInt, 
        @FormDataParam("lat") double latiTude, 
        @FormDataParam("longitude") double longiTude, 
        @FormDataParam("sessionid") String sessionID, 
        @FormDataParam("spid") String spID, 
        @FormDataParam("tr") int tR, 
        @FormDataParam("jsnum") int jsNum, 
        @FormDataParam("fingerprint") String fingerPrint, 
        @FormDataParam("methodset") MethodClass[][] methodSet) throws SQLException{
```

The way I tested in Postman are describe as below:

[image]

Comment: Is there a stack trace in the server logs?

Comment: 127.0.0.1 - - [29/Nov/2018:14:26:13 +0800] "POST /AdaptiveAuthWSApps/rest/AdaptiveService?uuid=13a1a079-4a39-4625-91a4-ddbf09c2c324&browserinfo=Mozilla%2F8.0%20%28Windows%20NT%206.1%29%20AppleWebKit%2F537.36%20%28KHTML%2C%20like%20Gecko%29%20Chrome%2F49.0.2623.112%20Safari%2F537.36&ipint=16885247&lat=1&longitude=0&sessionid=12w3e4&spid=https%3A%2F%2Fuap&tr=10&jsnum=2&fingerprint=yh8u87&methodset=1%2C1 HTTP/1.1" 404 1078

Comment: That's not a stack trace. A stack trace is a list of the method calls leading up to an exception, and the exception with the exception message. Is there an exception thrown on the backend?

Comment: No exception thrown at backend. It just display the below msg at Postman: HTTP Status 415 Unsupported Media Type
The origin server is refusing to service the request because the payload format is not supported by this method on the target resource.

Comment: FYI I'm using Tomcat 9 and OpenJDK8

Comment: Add `@Consumes(MediaType.MULTIPART_FORM_DATA)`. Does anything change (like exception thrown)?

Comment: Hi Paul, Everything is same. No log provided (exception thrown)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/184451/discussion-between-paul-samsotha-and-iza-izyani).

Answer (score 0):

Solution.
1. Remove header value in SOAP UI.
2. I was unable to process an array in Jersey. Instead of process MethodClass [][] methodSet, I'm sending the value one by one.
3. I also change back from MediaType.MULTIPART_FORM_DATA to MediaType.PLAIN_TEXT

My code is working now.

Thanks for the help.